# How to convert a String value to a given data type stored in another String?

Tags: java, string, types, casting

Suppose I have a String variable 'value' and a string variable 'type'. I want to cast the data in variable 'value' to the type specified by the variable 'type'.
Eg:

```
String value = "3.14";
String type = "float";
float result;
```

Using just the above two variables I need to fill in the variable 'result' with value 3.14. Also it would be great if a casting method can be used for non-primitive types.

Comment: Check my answer it might help you.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use a switch and write a case for every possible data type Ex:

```
switch (type){

case "float": 
float result = Float.parseFloat(value);
break;
....
case "int":
int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
break;
...
}
```

and so on for every possible data type

Comment: That's the idea, but you can't switch on a string in JAVA.

Comment: you can not pass string in switch that why I used if condition to do that

Comment: you can switch on string from Java SE 7 onwards

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh Interesting, I didn't know.

Comment: Is'nt there a way to do this apart from using a switch statement? As in some inbuilt function that can directly do this? What about non-primitive types?

Comment: well different types of data give different type of results how would you know what kind of data to expect? plus for ex: 100 can be parsed as int, float,double and so on ... 
For non-primitive types you have to write your own methods to extract the data from the String.

Comment: @sp00m This is not correct. You can use String types in the case

Answer (score 1):

Use like this to convert the `String` having decimal number to `Float`. So you can do same like this process for others.

```
double result = 0.0;
if(type.equals("float")
    result = Float.parseFloat(value);
else if(type.equals("int");
    result = Integer.parseInt(value);
else if(type.equals("double");
    result = Double.parseDouble(value);
```

Or

You can use switch statement. But you can not pass the string in switch till Java SE6 and Java SE 7 allow you to pass string also.